# How can I install MongoDB 2.6.x on Ubuntu 16.0.4 from tarball?

Tags: mongodb

I need to install MongoDB 2.6.x which is a requirement for Iquidus Explorer. No point in asking me to use a newer version as the code has never been updated to work with later versions of MongoDB.

MongoDB no longer has v2.6.x on any of its repositories so has to be installed from tarball.

I'm following the best set of instructions I can find for doing this at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/

I get down to step 2 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-tarball/#run-mongodb

I then get this error after running this command

```
~# mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
```

mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libnetsnmpagent.so.30: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone provide instructions that work?

Comment: Found more appropriate instructions for v2.6 at https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu/
Am trying these now

Comment: Looks better now. Getting the below...
~# mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 27712
child process started successfully, parent exiting

Comment: Please don't add additional detail via comment; many read only your original question (which you can edit, to correct for your new situation).

Answer (score 0):

It seems "[the more appropriate instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-ubuntu/)" is missing a dependency.

Your error says that the file `libnetsnmpagent.so.30` is missing so you have to install the packages that contains this file.

To find out what package contains this file, run the following commands to install `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Now, run the following command to find the package you need:

```
sudo apt-file search libnetsnmpagent.so.30
```

It should return: `libsnmp30`. Run the following commands to install this package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libsnmp30
```

Answer (score 0):

For once the fact that the Ubuntu packages massively lag the MongoDB releases work in your favor. The Ubuntu package of [mongodb-server](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mongodb-server) for 16.04 is locked to 2.6.x (looks like the latest one is 2.6.10) which would satisfy your needs.

Therefore all you should need to do is remove any official MongoDB repositories from your `apt` config, run `apt udpate` so that you default back to the Ubuntu repos and then run `apt install mongodb-server`

Alternatively you can just grab that 2.6.10 package [directly](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/mongodb-server/download) and install it manually with `dpkg`.